# Problems with nav bar positioning

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a nav bar and the positioning of the elements seem to be off. I have been trying to find the problem but the code looks fine to me

### The issues

- Navbar links seem to overflow when there is no need for it.
- `navbar-expand-md` isn't working. And so when I resize the page it looks completely wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1;    
}

body {   
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

nav {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', Sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    width: 100%;
 }

.navbar { 
 margin: 0; 
 padding-top: 1.5em; 
    padding-bottom: 1.5em; 
    padding-left: 6em;
    padding-right: 6em;
    border: none;
 list-style-type: none; 
 background-color: #000; 
 } 

.logo {
    float: left;
}

.navbar-brand {
    padding-left: 6px;
    text-decoration: none; 
 color: #fff; 
 background-color: #000; 
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline; 
}

.navbar ul li {  
 display: inline; 
 } 
 

.navbar ul li a {
    right: 6em !important;
 text-decoration: none; 
 color: #fff; 
 background-color: #000; 
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    right: 6em;
 } 

.nav-link {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.navs {
 float: right;   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">

    <link rel="icon" href="9h.png">
    <title>9haus Studios</title>
    <link href="graphic-design.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

    <script   src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      
    <script   src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"   integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
      
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-feJI7QwhOS+hwpX2zkaeJQjeiwlhOP+SdQDqhgvvo1DsjtiSQByFdThsxO669S2D" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
      
  </head>

  <body>
 

    
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="logo"><img src="9haus-logo-white.png" alt="9haus logo" width="63px" height="19px"></a>   
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="graphic-design.html">Graphic design</a>
  <div class="navs">
    <ul class="navbar-brand">
      <li class="active"><a class="nav-link" href="graphic-design.html">Work</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="graphic-studio.html">Studio</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a></li>
    </ul> 
    </div>  
</div>      
</nav>     
     
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You might want to check out the docs for [navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/) - the markup you have at the moment doesn't really match what the CSS is built for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is `nav {width:100%}` it should be `nav {width:auto}`.

Comment: Nice! That worked for the first problem. Any Idea what the problem is with 'navbar-expand-md' in the html?